# SetScale unintentionally affecting SKSpriteNode position

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, scale

I'm making my first shooter game using Swift and SpriteKit and I've recently been running into problems with `setScale()`. I have a `Laser` class whose instances are added as children to a `Ship` class. I now realize that any down scaling of the parent node will scale its child as well. In my `update` method in `GameScene` I check the position of each child named 'Laser' to determine if it should be removed from its parent when offscreen. I recently updated some of my sprites- including their relative sizes, and I noticed that the position of each laser is way off, as they are removed far before they reach the end of the screen and upon debugging their x positions are in fact far larger than where they are displayed onscreen. I also noticed that the starting x of each `Laser` instance is relative to its original position within the `Ship` instance. So the ship may be halfway across the screen but the laser x position still starts at 0 and if the ship is able to pass the laser, the laser's position becomes negative--is there a way to grab its position on the screen rather than relative to its start within its parent?

This is the code I'm doing the check with:

```
    self.aShip.gun.enumerateChildNodesWithName("laser",
        usingBlock: { node, _ in
            if let aLaser = node as? Laser {  i
               if(aLaser.position.x > self.size.width){                              
                  aLaser.removeFromParent()
               }
            }
        }
    )
```

It seems like scaling has a ton more baggage than I would normally assume, so any insight into this problem or how to manage the relation between code and sprites would be awesome!!

EDIT:

I found that adding `let positionInScene = self.convertPoint(aLaser.position, fromNode: self.aShip.gun)` under `if let aLaser = node as? Laser {`and consequently using `positionInScene` rather than the `aLaser` position works.. however, I still don't fully understand the scaling effect going on with `aLaser` and it's position and don't know if its efficient to have to convert positions like this at the rate of `update` (60 times a second).

Comment: Is the laser a "projectile" or something of that sort? The SKView has an automatic node culling feature that removes nodes when they leave the screen. It might suit your need to just use this automatic feature. Also, check your physics body size vs the size of the texture - the physics body might be larger, causing the discrepancy.

Comment: @R.P.Carson the laser is a projectile that spawns from the ship. Would the automatic node culling feature work for specific nodes? At this point, I want to figure out what I'm not understanding about `setscale`. My physics body is what I think it is as I've been using `showPhysics` to outline each sprite.

Comment: 1) make sure anchor point is at (.5,.5) 2) make sure the laser becomes a child of scene not of gun (use `moveToParent` after you fire the laser)

Comment: @R.P.Carson, it does not remove the node from the scene,  just from drawing to the scene

Comment: @knight0fDragon How would you suggest reaching the scene? The structure is: `Laser` is a child of `Gun`, `Gun` is a child of `Ship`, and `Ship` is a child of the scene. Would it make sense to just call `parent?.parent?.parent`?

Comment: Every node knows it scene. Just do .scene

Comment: @knight0fDragon That's incredibly useful, I never knew you could reference it like that. After implementing it I realized that the laser isn't scaled along with the ship. Does it make sense to still do this instead of `let positionInScene = self.convertPoint(aLaser.position, fromNode: self.aShip.gun)` on each check in update? I imagine the latter is more expensive? Also any advice in general on scaling sprites? As I wrote before, I've been making my sprite textures much larger for detail and then shrinking them in-game, is this not a proper method? (It seems that setScale works poorly)